# Html2Canvas removes the leading empty lines

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'd like to take a screenshot of a text area. I use `html2canvas` for this as I found in some example.

The problem is that if the words have empty lines above them, `html2canvas` removes these lines and just takes a screenshot for the words from the beginning of the field.

**HTML:**

```
Welcome there

</textarea>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #target {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}
button {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("target");
  //textarea.style.height =300 + "px";
  html2canvas(textarea, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
  });
}
```

How can I just take a screenshot for the text area as it is without shifting the words to the beginning?

Here is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/uwkgd6yn/2/

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with several workarounds: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2008 & https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/83